# Get somebody out Vs take somebody off

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

I'm going to tell once someone that someone else helped me get off the bus; (e.g. when my leg was broken etc.) Do the following sentences mean the same? Are they interchangeable here:

> - He **got me out** of the bus.
> - He **took me off** the bus.
> - He **got me off** the bus.

Comment: Did you break your leg because the bus crashed?

Comment: If this person helped you off the bus, why wouldn't you just say, "He **helped me off** the bus."

Answer (score 3):

> out of the bus

implies leaving the bus in an unconventional way, for example after a crash when one might leave via an emergency exit or window

we normally leave by

> getting off the bus

If you were carried, this works

> He got me off the bus

and that's what I's use if I were describing carrying my grandson off the bus.

If you were given support but participated in the motion then J.R.'s suggestion is better:

> He helped me get off the bus

or

> He helped me off the bus